# Execute exe on remote machine

Tags: c#, remote-server, psexec

I'm trying to execute notepad.exe on a remote machine, but it's not working now. What am I missing?

```
var ui = new ImpersonateUser();
    //the process to restart
    const string processName = "notepad.exe";
    var serverName = "serverName";

    try
    {
        //Use adbadmin for access
        ui.Impersonate(_domain, _userName, _pass);

        //Start the process
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
        info.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";
        info.Arguments = @"""\\" + serverName + @"C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe""";
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = Process.Start(info);

        lblStatusResponse.Text = "Service " + processName + " was restarted correctly.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatusResponse.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        ui.Undo();
    }
```

This gives me no exception, but I'm surely missing something...

Comment: Is the "server" service started on the remote machine?

Comment: for one thing, you need a space before C:\..

Comment: @LorenzoDematté What to you mean with server service?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Where? On all of them?

Comment: no, just here: `info.Arguments = @"""\\" + serverName + @" C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe""";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was a combination from your replies. But the whole correct solution was:

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
        info.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";
        info.Arguments = @"\\" + serverName + @" -i C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

Answer (score 4):

Running an interactive program such as notepad.exe doesn't always open a visible window on the target PC. Try opening Task Manager on the target PC while you run the code and see if notepad.exe appears in the list of running processes.

I'd suggest trying to run psexec from the command line first before attempting to call it via code.

```
psexec \\serverName "notepad.exe"
```

You may also want to use the "interactive" flag so it can interact with the desktop on the target.

```
psexec \\serverName "notepad.exe" -i
```

Comment: It didn't start the process either, I checked

Comment: Do you receive an error when running on the cmd line? Are both the source and target PC's connected to the same domain? If so, does the account that is running the psexec command have permissions on the target PC? Try adding the account to the local admin group on the target workstation.

Comment: Another test you can try is to attempt to map a network drive from the source PC to the target PC. Try running the following from the command line.     net use \\serverName\c$

Comment: No errors. Hmm...The domain is the same. The permissions are correct as well

Comment: Try checking whether ports 135 and 445 are open on the target servers firewall.

Comment: There are no port problems =/

Answer (score 2):

Your UNC path does not look good.

After the string concatenation, it will look something like

```
  "\\serverNameC:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe"
```

Try to print it out. See documentation about [UNC on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx), and some examples [here](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm) (or google about UNC Path)

If you have only the default shares, it should be something like

```
  "\\serverName\C$\WINDOWS\notepad.exe"
```

OR psexec let you use a different notation, but you have to be careful with double quotes there

```
  psexec \\serverName"c:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe"
```

Also, ensure that the "Server" service is running on the target machine.

> PsExec starts an executable on a remote system and controls the input and output streams of the executable's process so that you can interact with the executable from the local system. PsExec does so by extracting from its executable image an embedded Windows service named Psexesvc and copying it to the Admin$ share of the remote system. PsExec then uses the Windows Service Control Manager API, which has a remote interface, to start the Psexesvc service on the remote system.

The Admin$ share is created and managed by the "Server" service, so you need it running for psexec to work (http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec).

Comment: Now when you mention it, I will try the C$

Comment: You should also try using it at the command line, first. Then when it works, embed it in your C# program. It's easier that way...

Comment: Hmm ok..Psexec is on the server so that shouldn't be a problem. But the commandline am I not sure of

Comment: psexec runs on your machine. It "pulls out" a service (embedded in its own resources), copies it to the server or "target" machine, and starts it. The copy happens using the Admin$ share; that's why "Server" needs to be started (automatically or manually)

Comment: Not really sure what you talk about when you say "server". Reading documentation it says you don't need to install any software on the remote machine..?

Comment: I've tried @"\\" + serverName + @"C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe"; and @"\\" + serverName + @"C$\WINDOWS\notepad.exe";. Nothing works

Comment: I've got it working now. With @"\\" + serverName + @" -i C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe";

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend current version of answer.
There could be a problem of execution `psexec` due to OS policy, to enable remote control you need to modify registry:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

You can check this: [Remote UAC LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942817/how-to-change-the-remote-uac-localaccounttokenfilterpolicy-registry-se)