# How to invoke an exe located remotely on system

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have used the code posted on link  [Execute exe on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782308/execute-exe-on-remote-machine)
and changed notepad location on the line
`info.Arguments = @"\\" + serverName + @" -i C:\WINDOWS\System32\notepad.exe";`  ,but still throws error like 
"The system cannot find the file specified" ,any idea why this error is causing.My destination system is windows 2008 R2 server

Comment: Is PsExec installed on the remote system?

Comment: You don't need that code to run programs remotely. A simple `Enter-PSSession servername` in Powershell is enough to start a new session wihtout installing `psexec` or anything else. You can create a remote Powershell pipeline in code very easily as well

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos how to do it??

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error how to know psexec is installed on remote server

Comment: Well, if you install it then you'll know it's there...

Comment: To clarify, PsExec is a utility - it's not part of a standard Windows installation.

Comment: I installed psexec,now no error coming ,but notepad is not opening remotely

Comment: i have persmission issue ,which i will solve

Answer (score 1):

There are two notepad.exe available in "C:\"

1. In Windows directory like "c:\Windows\notepad.exe"
2. In System32 directory like "c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"

If you want to access notepad.exe in the System32 directory then you want administrator credentials.

## Suggestion: use "c:\Windows\notepad.exe" this one.

Comment: i dont have c:\Windows\notepad.exe

Comment: Check this one "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe"