# C# - Trying to start an exe located on a server

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a program for work that installs a list of software on newly imaged laptops. The installers are located on a server and we map into it by "//[server ip]/folder/. However whenever I initiate the method to start the installer, my program freezes.

I was able to test with a local installer, but it worked just fine. Is there a step I may have missed?

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AppInstall install = new AppInstall();

            Console.WriteLine("Starting installation");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\{Server-IP}\Software_Depot\Installers_Master\Snagit\v2019\snagit.exe", "/q");
            Console.WriteLine("install started");

        }
```

The program should be running with my current credentials which are allowed to connect to this folder. I want to be able to install snagit once I click this button.

Comment: Please provide the Exception that's being thrown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I launch files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283584/how-do-i-launch-files-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute exe on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782308/execute-exe-on-remote-machine)

Comment: Try running as Administrator...